# Class 'HttpResponse' not found in document

Tags: php, pear, pecl

I realize this question has been asked before, but the other thread does not seem to have provided the answer. I have installed `PEAR` and `PECL_http` extension, but I am still getting this error. Do I need to include a file before using this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you run `phpinfo()` in a script, do those extensions appear in the list?  Have you modified your php.ini and added?  Have you restarted Apache or your web server (assuming you are viewing in a web browser)?

Comment: Mmm... I'm using a hosting service that installed it for me. I see in my cPanel that PEAR and PECL_http is installed. I'm just stuck on how to use it. You don't need to include any files before calling HttpResponse, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the extension in `php.ini` and restart your web server. Then use `phpinfo()` to verify it's loaded.

Comment: I have installed the extension, added it in php.ini, it shows up in phpinfo(), but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?